# Тип сглаживания текста на веб-странице

Tags: html, css

Браузер Chrome (Windows 10) работает с двумя вкладками. В одной из них отображается Gmail, и на этой странице все шрифты имеют серое сглаживание.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также в соседней вкладке того же браузера на другой странице шрифты отображаются с использованием RGB сглаживания.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Какая настройка или CSS-свойство влияет на это поведение?

Comment: По CSS вроде просто, можно в dev console галки поснимать и понять CSS это или нет.

Comment: Это не CSS, у CSS-а всегда RGB сглаживание. (подозреваю что это картинка)

Comment: @ΝNL993 нет конечно.

Comment: Это зависит от кучи факторов вплоть до фазы луны. В основном на это влияют трансформации и прозрачность, но может быть что-то ещё.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCYpB.png Вот даже тут левая колонка чёрно-белая, а основной текст цветной.